# "How will I know?" vs "How should I know?"

Tags: meaning, expressions

When I am asked some question, and I don't know the answer, which is the right answer?

> 1. How will I know?
> 2. How should I know?

And what is the difference between the two expressions?

Answer (score 3):

**How will I know?** is asking about a future event such as "How will I know when the meat is cooked?" (possible answer "When the thermometer reaches 70C")

**How should I know?** Is a possible answer, but in British English it is usually regarded as being rather rude or abrupt and often said in an annoyed way. For example "Q. Why is the bus late?" "A. How should I know? I don't run the bus company."

The polite way of answering would be simply **"I don't know"**.

Answer (score 0):

We can use 'should' with 'why' and 'how'.

'**How should** I know?' shows that I am angry. When we answer a question angrily we say 'How should I know?' We can say in a normal way- 'I don't know'.

When we don't understand something we say '**Why should**...'

**How will** he/she etc. know?- a question indicating future.

[ **What shall** I do?= **What should** I do? (to ask for advice) ]